# How to send an email if there is an validation error while saving record

Tags: apex, email, validation-rule, before-trigger

Hi I want to send out an email if the record insert is failed due to validation rule, even though I have before insert trigger and also it is invoking send mail method, But I'm not receiving mail kindly let me know what is the issue

```
trigger sendEmailOnValidation on Account (before Insert) {


    for(Account a : trigger.new){
    system.debug('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
    test_email.send_email();
    system.debug('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
    }
}
```

Send Email Class and Method

```
public class test_email {
    public static void send_email(){
        string client_email1 = 'support@cloudexpertsindia.com';        
          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
              String[] addr1=new String[]{};
                 addr1.add(client_email1);
                 mail1.setToAddresses(addr1);         
                 mail1.setSubject('Before Inserting Record'); 
                 mail1.setBccSender(false);
                 mail1.setUseSignature(false);
                 mail1.setHtmlBody('<p><b> Record has created from MyFunction </b></p>');
                 Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail1 });
    }
}
```

Comment: is your email Deliverability set to `All access` ? check debbug logs if you are getting any error or not

Comment: Did you try to insert a try{}Catch - and send email on the catch action?

Comment: this is not possible; VRs rollback everything, including the email.  You would need a different strategy (e.g. soft alerts)

Answer (score 1):

See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm?search_text=order%20of%20execution). The LAST thing that happens after DML operations (#20) is email is sent. If you failed validation, any email sent through a class in a Before Insert trigger won't ever be sent. It will be rolled back just like all the rest of the DML in the execution context.